minimum hardware requirement of solana RPC node
I need to set up a server to run a Solana RPC node. My requirements are:
① The node must remain in sync with the latest data and cannot fall behind.
② The node should deploy Geyser Plugins to monitor all token transaction information. Once a transaction is detected, I need to be able to retrieve the transaction data (tx data) and then send this information to my program for processing.
③ I do not need to store historical data.
What is the minimum hardware configuration required to deploy such an RPC? The official recommendation is 256 GB of RAM and a 2 TB hard drive. Due to my specific requirements, can I reduce the amount of RAM and disk space?

Oficcial recommendation is outdate, you will need +1TB ram for index all acounts

what if we do not need all accounts? would it even be possible to limit it to a few accounts though?
